# Couldn't install tableauhyperapi python module

Tags: python, pip, tableau-api

I'm trying to install `tableauhyperapi` python module on macOS M1 with simple `pip install tableauhyperapi`, but facing the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tableauhyperapi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tableauhyperapi
```

Tried the same install for Ubuntu 18.04 and was facing the same result.

Comment: Are you using a 64-bit version of python?

Comment: @vizyourdata, yeah.